# Why using network provider for location updates in Android GPS gives device time?

Tags: android, gps

While using network provider for location updates, I found that it is the same time that I set on my device. Can it not be that provided by network as it goes when it is GPS. Or if network provider cannot provide time , then atleast location.getTime() should return 0 instead of device time. Is there any way to avoid device time, as I want to distinguish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network provider doesnt supply your phone with a time as GPS does. There is no way to change that.

It's because network provider is using the locations of the GPRS/EDGE/WIFI/3G antennas your phone is connected to and calculates an aproximate position out of it - there is no specific "network location" service.

GPS or `Navigational Satellite Timing and Ranging - Global Positioning System` (NAVSTAR GPS) on the other hand is designed for transmitting an atomic-clock exact timing signal.

Comment: Hmm... But atleast location.getTime() should return null instead of device time to indicate it cannot give it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return **null** because when it's null, it'll use system time.
You can refer to the source code of **`Location.class`**

```
if (mTime == 0) 
   mTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```